# What's the proof of the expectation of a discrete random variable?

Tags: statistics

One of the fundamental formulas in Statistics is that of the expectation of a discrete random variable, which is given by: $E(X)= \sum_{\text{all }x} x \cdot P(X=x)$. How does one prove this? Should a beginning undergraduate to Stats simply accept this?

Comment: That is the usual definition of the expectation....how do you define it?

Comment: It is a definition that is consistent with our notion of average.

Comment: You could try proof by induction on $N$, the number of distinct outcomes. It's really easy to show the formula works for $N=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents: Expectation is the average when the outcomes are equally likely. If the outcomes are not equally likely, the expectation is the weighted average. The weight of each value is the probability that the random variable to take that value.

You may also look at it as the limit of the average of n independent observations of the random variable (i.e. average of values when rolling a dice n times when n is large). This is called the law of large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the definition of probability. We define $p(x)$ as the fraction of the trials that yield an outcome of $x$ in the limit that the number of trials goes to infinity. We can write the average of $x$ in $N$ trials as:

$$\left<x\right>_N = \sum_x q(x) x$$

where $q(x)$ is the fraction of the trials that yielded $x$. In the limit of $N$ to infinity the $q(x)$ will converge to $p(x)$, and the average of $x$ is that limit is called the expectation value. So, the formula for the expectation value follows from the fact that the observed fractions of outcomes in a finite trial converge to the probabilities as given by the probability distribution in the limit of an infinite number of trials.